# After Effects: Move a layer after Position keyframes have been added

Tags: position, layer, effects, keyframe

I'm not sure how to word this question.

So here's an example. 
The animation on a layer slides into view, and bounces back slightly.
Easy peasy.

The Position Keyframes look something like this:

Keyframe 0: (-100,200)
Keyframe 10: (100,200)
Keyframe 15: (125,200)
Keyframe 20: (100,200)

Let's say I want to move this layer, because I don't like where it's vertically positioned. So, I've been selecting each Keyframe (0,10,15,20) and manually changing the Y-axis to whatever number.

Is there an easier way to do this?
I'd like to be able to highlight the layer in the timeline, [press some button] + drag to where I would like it to be on the Y-axis, and the keyframes update themselves

Answer (score 8):

Two ways to do this;

1. Create a null object (new layer - null object), and attach the animated layer to the null object (click and drag the swirly icon on the animated layer - drag it to the null layer and it should parent to the null layer). Now you can move the position of the null layer and it will move the animated layer, preserving your keyframes.
2. If you make sure the playhead is over one of the keyframes, and highlight ALL your keyframes, then when you move the position of the layer (e.g move Y up 150) it will apply the same move to all keyframes.